# What does kotlin-bom library do?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I've created new Kotlin project under Gradle. By default it sets this dependencies to the Kotlin-library project. And I wonder what does this **kotlin-bom** lib do ?

```
dependencies {
    // Align versions of all Kotlin components
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))

    // Use the Kotlin JDK 8 standard library.
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // Use the Kotlin test library.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")

    // Use the Kotlin JUnit integration.
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}
```

Comment: BOM refers to a "Bill of Materials" as defined by Maven. Described here https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Create an answer that contains the quotes: "Imports are most effective when used for defining a "library" of related artifacts that are generally part of a multiproject build..." and "The root of the project is the BOM pom...." and you're all set for some upvotes I guess.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks! Was kind of debating with myself which parts of that page are relevant here.

Comment: Probably needs some Kotlin specific part too, such as a general description of what is included. Specifics don't seem necessary, that's what the BOM is for, I suppose :P

Comment: I'm not confident enough in my amateurish experience with this stuff to commit to an answer. If anyone else cares to pitch in, please do :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `kotlin-bom` artifact is a dependency-only POM that aligns all the Kotlin SDK libraries with the same version.

See [the POM content for version 1.5.31](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-bom/1.5.31/kotlin-bom-1.5.31.pom) for an example. It uses the POM's `dependencyManagement` section to depend on the same version of all the Kotlin SDK artifacts, like `kotlin-stdlib`, `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`, `kotlin-reflect`, `kotlin-test`, etc.

Description of a BOM:

> Software bill of materials (BOMs) don’t specify a dependency on a
> module or file, but instead are a list of version constraints for
> other components. They define what is called a platform, which is
> basically a list of components with specific versions that are known
> to play well together and/or form a useful unit of functionality. It’s
> worth mentioning that not all of the dependencies listed in the BOM
> actually have to be included in your projects — it’s basically a way
> of saying “If you use any of these modules, use this version”.
> -- [A deep dive into an initial Kotlin build.gradle.kts](https://medium.com/@gabrielshanahan/a-deep-dive-into-an-initial-kotlin-build-gradle-kts-8950b81b214)